# Reestablishing Automatic and Secure FTP Connection, Primary Domain Change

Tags: wp-admin, domain, ftp

Action: Changed my primary domain address.

Result: Caused WordPress to ask for FTP passcode every time I make a change from the WordPress interface.

Active Issue: I would like to reestablish a safe & secure connection between my server and WordPress portal so as not to have to enter my FTP password every time I make a change.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is usually either safe and secure or user friendly, very hard to have them both. In this case what you ask means that PHP can write to wordpress folders which means that any bug in a plugin or theme might be escalated to a full control of your site.

If you still prefer to be less safe and secure, you should check the permission of the wordpress directories to make sure the web server is allowed to write to them. The codex is a good place to look for inspiration - https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions